# Is deleting contents of AppData folder from my computer recommended?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive

Well well well...my computer keeps on eating whatever free space is available in the hard drive. It doesn't care whether the free space is in kb,KB,MB or GB. It happens only in the C drive where my OS & other program files are installed.

I used a software Windir Stat or something like that (I don't remember the name exactly) to analyze the usage of space by various programs.

In my C drive, there's a folder named AppData with loads of useless files. I don't know whether they are useful or not? Are they useful?

I was thinking about deleting the contents of that folder. I visited [THIS LINK](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-8/what-appdata-folder) for more info. WHich folder should I delete???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not delete anything manually unless you know what it is, Appdata folder contains files/settings for programs to run correctly. If you are running low on disk space, I suggest you look into disk cleaning applications such as CCleaner.

You could also remove shadow copies, reduce hibernation space and much more which is a lot safer than randomly removing files.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally not recommended. That's not to say you can never delete stuff from there but you would really need to know you're way around the AppData folder to make any changes.

The Appdata folder is where programs store user specific settings. For example let's take Outlook. When you customize how it looks those customisations are saved in the AppData folder. Another example is Outlook saving your signatures there. Take IE as another example. I think this is where it stores your temporary internet files. So if you delete the AppData folder then you'll lose all those.